# Stripe Prebuilt Checkout Session Returns 404 Error In Laravel 8

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I'm having an extremely frustrting time implementing Stripe's Prebuilt Checkout Page in Laravel 8.  After research I've adjusted my controller as follows

```
 // We grab the Stripe key information we added in the .env file
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('####');

        // Creates the Stripe session
        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create ([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
            'shipping_address_collection' => ['allowed_countries' => ['US', 'CA'],],
            'line_items' => [[
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'product_data' => [
                   'name' => 'T-shirt',
               ],
                    'unit_amount' => $total_amount*100,
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
            'success_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/',
        ]);

        // Return the Stripe Session id so the fetch command in our frontend redirects users to Stripe's checkout page
        return response()->json(['id' => $session->id]);
```

The code in my routes.web file is Route::post('/stripe/order', [StripeController::class, 'payment']);

I made sure my form looks like so

```
<form action="/stripe/order" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                            @csrf
```

And some javascript code like so...

```
 // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe('####');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Create a new Checkout Session using the server-side endpoint you
        // created in step 3.
        fetch('/stripe/order', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'url': '/stripe/order',
                "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('input[name=_token]').value
            },
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(session) {
            return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, you should display the localized error message to your
            // customer using `error.message`.
            if (result.error) {
                alert(result.error.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });
```

Does anybody know why it is returning a 404 error?

Comment: clear your route cache and composer dump-autoload. If still remains, post your whole StripeController class

Comment: Still no dice here is the stripe class    Due to the length of the class, I have to post in two messages. \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('');

        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create ([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
            'shipping_address_collection' => ['allowed_countries' => ['US', 'CA'],],

Comment: Part two of the controller class is here                                                          
              'line_items' => [[
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'product_data' => [
                   'name' => 'T-shirt',
               ],
                    'unit_amount' => $total_amount*100,
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],

Comment: Here is part 3 of the controller sorry for not being able to format it for easier read  
           'mode' => 'payment',
            'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
            'success_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/',
        ]);

        return response()->json(['id' => $session->id]);

Comment: Have you pinpointed what specifically is failling here? Is it the request to Stripe that is failling or is it something else?

Comment: After some tinkering to my route.web file, I changed the form action to {{  route('stripe.checkout') }}, which removes the 404 error, but now I get a white page with {"id":"cs_test_b1oPXQc5XLk2IW95pyDq7UCgbOrqdgTVn4rTFlGJMM90LCLwoc5QXXc7Mo"}

Comment: I managed to fix the 404 error by updating my form action with {{ route('stripe.checkout') }}, but now I get a generic id token like so.  {"id":"cs_test_b1rEQO0qc6Q1bkpkGWLiy89u0xJY4qouRJzEapNhBCaaFUZiM3whuptPKw"}.  It must be coming from stripe at this point

Comment: When I do a die dump with laravel, there is connectivity with the stripe checkout session, but it only returns a id token. Hope this helps to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Isn't getting back `{"id":"cs_test_b1rEQO0qc6Q1bkpkGWLiy89u0xJY4qouRJzEapNhBCaaFUZiM3whuptPKw"}` what you want? Your code uses that ID in `stripe.redirectToCheckout()` to redirect to the Checkout page

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I had to change the session to redirect to the url....